# What does the slash / do in SAS data step?

Tags: sas

I am reading someone else's code and I discovered a syntax that I had never seen:

```
data _quotes / view=_quotes;

...

run;
```

I am a little bit confused by the syntax `_quotes / view` here. What does it do in particular?

Comment: Creates a view not a data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash on the data step marks beginning of options. The `VIEW=` option says to create a data step view.  So `work._quotes` will be a view and not a physical dataset.